# Left bit shift 0 in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Consider:

```
   int a = 0;
   a |= 1 << a;
   System.out.println(a);
```

It prints "1". Why? I thought left bit shifting 0 by any number of times was still 0. Where's it pulling the 1 from?

Comment: ohhhh it ought to be a<<1!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression `1 << a;` will shift the value `1`, `a` number of times.

In other words, you have the value 1:

```
0000001
```

Now, you shift the whole thing over 0 bits to the left.  You then have:

```
0000001
```

You then have:

```
a |= 1 << a;
```

Which resolves to:

```
a = 0000000 | 0000001
```

Or:

```
a = 1;
```

You might have the operands mixed up.  If you're trying to shift the value 0 one bit to the left, you'd want:

```
a |= a << 1;
```

Comment: LHS there should be all 0's, shouldn't it?

Comment: @yshavit - Not following.

Comment: a is 0, so it should be `0 | 1`

Comment: @yshavit - Oh you were talking about `a |= a << 1;`.  Correct, `a` is zero so the expression resolves to `a = 0 | 1;`

Comment: Yup, sorry I wasn't more specific -- hard to type on an iPad. :) I already +1'd you for explaining it right other than that typo.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the operator << in a wrong way.
It must to be:

```
int a = 0;
a |= a << 1;
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are left shifting the literal `1` by the variable `a`. The value of variable `a` is zero. `1<<0 = 1`

So you've just got your variables flipped. Try reversing the variables.

Comment: This answer could be more affirmative. There shouldn't be much doubt the outcome.